# How can I imread the image that I cropped with imcrop into a variable?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've tried this but it failed;

```
Face = imcrop(I, bboxes(1,:));
TestImage = imread(Face);
```

This is the error.

> Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 457).The filename or url
>   argument must be a string.

Is there any other function or method that I can use?

Comment: why your  using imread ? . imread return image matrix only which you  get from imcrop. So my opinion there is no need for imread. if you want  to get data from imread then use **imwrite(Imagematrix , Path)** function for save that image after then use the imread(path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read an image, it should be present as an image file. For that, first, you should use `imwrite` to save your image matrix into an image file, then you could use `imread`.

**Try this:**

```
Face = imcrop(I, bboxes(1,:));      %// Your code
imwrite(Face,'Face.jpg');           %// saving in default path
TestImage = imread('Face.jpg');     %// reading with same filename & default path
```

Also note that doing this is meaningless because, both `Face` and `TestImage` have the same values. You should avoid doing this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do has no meaning, because you have already read the image into the `Face` variable, and you do not need to read it again. However, you can copy it to another variable or write it as an image using `imwrite`.

```
Face = imread('circuit.tif');            % read the file into the face variable
croppedFace = imcrop(I,[75 68 130 112]); % crop the image and save it in a new variable
```